# Pass sql variable into PHP variable then back into sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to select the highest value in a table:

```
$max = "SELECT MAX(pid) FROM pic";
```

Then pass that value into a PHP variable:

```
$results_max = $conn->query($max);
$highest_val = $results_max->fetch_assoc();
```

To then use again in a SQL insert statement:

```
$sql_update = "UPDATE users 
            SET username = '$username', pid = '$highest_val'
            WHERE username = '$username'";
```

However i tested out the value i got from my first select statement (`$highest_val`) and it returns `"Array"`. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Edit:

```
$sql_update = "UPDATE users 
            SET username = '$username', pic_id = '$highest_val[pid]'
            WHERE username = '$username'" ;
```

Comment: use `$highest_val['pid']` instead of `$highest_val`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create alias of `MAX(pid);`

```
$max = "SELECT MAX(pid) as pid FROM pic";
```

Now you fetch max pid using

```
$results_max = $conn->query($max);
$highest = $results_max->fetch_assoc();
$highest_val =$highest['pid'];// pass column name here
```

And your Update query would be

```
$sql_update = "UPDATE users 
            SET username = '".$username."', pid = '".$highest_val."'
            WHERE username = '".$username."'";
```

Comment: this is working! sort of... I am getting `Warning Illegal string offset` when i call the run the update statement

Comment: `echo  $sql_update = "UPDATE users 
            SET username = '$username', pid = '$highest_val'
            WHERE username = '$username'";` and check your update query or paste it here

Comment: i appreciate all the help! could you explain why you added the quotes and the periods? @Saty

Comment: Actually you are using  `$highest_val[pid]` in single quotes for which cause `Warning Illegal string offset`. We directly use single quotes inside double quotes so i write codes in double quotes